# GoogleMaps - calling onPause()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, lifecycle

I was wondering: When using Google Maps v2, the mapView should call

```
mapView.onPause()
```

in onPause().

Should however super.onPause() be called before mapView.onPause(), or afterwards? 
Should it be like this:

```
@Override          
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   mapView.onPause();
}
```

or like this:

```
@Override          
public void onPause()
{

   mapView.onPause();
   super.onPause();
}
```

? Both seem to work (no errors in the compiler nor while running the app), but what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for the latter. On methods `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` etc. call `super` first, to init all object internals  before you code may use it, while on `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` first cleanup your stuff then call `super` to let superclass do its job too, otherwise your code may try to depend on stuff that is no longer available after `super` cleaning completed.